# easy way to check up series of consistency in rails model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my ruby on rails project, I have a model of different parts: A, B, C. A has different fields, depending on that which entity of B and C may fit in. When user put A,B,C in cart I have to tell them if A,B,C these parts fits in or not?

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   def supports_x(B)
         ...
      return true
   end
   def supports_y(C)
         ...
      return true
   end
   ....10/15 methods like this


   def report(cart)
       report=[]
       if support_x(cart.a)
          report<<"a does not support x opporation"
       end
       .... like this 10/15 hand written if else operation.
   end
end
```

Personally I can do that, I can write 10/15 similar looking methods and if else blocks, but my instinct is telling me I am doing it wrong, I am violating DRY principle.

Is there any way I can avoid this in ruby/rails?

Comment: Is the logic in all your `support_` the same?

Comment: yep pretty much same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `method_missing` method like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

   def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
     if m.to_s.start_with? 'support_'
       # Check the full method name and do whatever you want with args
     else
       super
     end
   end


   def report(cart)
       report=[]
       parts = ['x', 'y', 'z']
       parts.each do |part|
         if self.send("support_#{part}", cart.a)
           report << "a does not support #{part} operation"
         end
       end
   end
end
```

Note that I haven't tested this, and it's more like a pseudocode to give you an idea.